# Windows Server 2003 as a Session Host in RDS 2012 R2

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services

I'm pretty sure that I know the answer to this question, however, I haven't yet found any information specifically stating what I believe.

Is it possible to use a Windows Server 2003 server as a session host for in a Windows Server 2012 R2 RDS deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the [licensing is not compatible](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14988.rds-and-ts-cal-interoperability-matrix.aspx) and according to the [Remote Desktop Services Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2014/01/29/remote-desktop-services-upgrade-and-migration-guidelines-for-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx), connection broker is not supported even when running in a mixed 2012 and 2012 R2 deployment.

> There is no interoperability between Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012/Windows Server 2012 R2. RD Connection Broker architecture changed in Windows Server 2012 release as such that no upgrade/interoperability is supported with earlier OS releases. Only the interop combinations mentioned in the blog above are supported.

All other roles only list compatibility between 2012 and 2012 R2, excluding lower versions.